# Relationship between directional derivative and gradient in x, y and z

Tags: mathematical-physics, partial-derivative

1. Can anybody explain the relationship between directional derivative and gradient?
2. What can I use the results of directional derivative and gradient for ?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then the derivative in the direction $v$ (i.e. $v$ is a unit vector) is $\nabla f(x)v$.

Comment: Are you trying to explain directional derivative or gradient? I am sorry, if I am asking you without understanding your answer

Comment: The comment I gave above is a (partial) definition of the directional derivative, given the gradient. This was always the more useful version for me, since when you have an analytic form for a function, the partial derivatives are relatively easy to find, but the directional derivatives are quite difficult.

Comment: I think you are answering my question considering I understand partial derivative well. I am trying to understand why we need directional derivative and gradient. Can you further explain about my question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot. (That is why I only gave you a comment and not a full answer)

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative is defined as

$$f'(x;v)=\lim_{t>0,\,t\to 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}.$$

It can exist even if the function $f$ is not differentiable. If the directional derivative is actually linear in the direction $v$, $f'(x;v)=Av$, one can assign this linear function $A$ as the total derivative. However, $f$ is only (Frechet) differentiable in $x$ if

$$f(x+v)=f(x)+Av+o(\|v\|)$$

that is, if the approximation by the linearization is uniformly good over all directions. Then $A$ is also written as $f'(x)$ or $Df_x$ or similar.

---

Now where does the gradient enter? Of course with a scalar product. The derivative $f'(x)$ of a scalar function, i.e., its Jacobian, is covector, linear functional, or in cartesian space, a row vector. The gradient $∇f(x)$ is the vector (in cartesian space column vector) associated to that row vector via

$$\langle \nabla f(x),v\rangle=f'(x)v.$$

In the standard euclidean setting in cartesian space, this relation is simple transposition, $$\nabla f(x)=f'(x)^T,$$ in curved space with non-trivial metric tensors, the relation is more complicated.